# How to update a field in database Django?

Tags: django

I need to update my student's total score for my application 
but the problem is that I can not update this value.

Models:

```
class Student(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    quizzes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz, through='TakenQuiz')
    total_score = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Estudantes'
```

Obs: The tota_score has default value = 0

views:

```
class TakenQuizListView(ListView):

model = TakenQuiz
context_object_name = 'taken_quizzes'
template_name = 'classroom/students/taken_quiz_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):        
    queryset = self.request.user.student.taken_quizzes \
        .select_related('quiz', 'quiz__subject') \
        .order_by('quiz__name')
    return queryset

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    total_score = self.request.user.student.total_score
    total_score  = Student.objects.get(total_score= 
  self.request.user.student.total_score)
    total_score = TakenQuiz.objects.aggregate(Sum('score'))
    total_score.save() #try update
    student = self.request.user.student

    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['total_score'] =  total_score['score__sum'] 
    return context
```

I can get the full score but i can not update the field in the models.

Comment: where is update code

Comment: Where in your code do you try to update a `Student` with the calculated score?

Comment: In total_score.save () but it shows an error

Comment: What are you trying to do? Update all students? Update the taken quizes? You should add the TakenQuiz model and show an example of expected behaviour.

Comment: Save student's total score in models.

Comment: But you never actually do that. There is no code here that does anything to store the calculated score anywhere.

Comment: Because I'm confused, I have no idea how to update the value in models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.

First, you need to calculate the total score just for the quizzes that were taken by the student, not by everyone:

```
student = self.request.user.student
total_score = TakenQuiz.objects.filter(student=student).aggregate(Sum('score'))
```

Now, you need to update the student's record with that value:

```
student.total_score = total_score['score__sum'] 
student.save()
```

Finally, you need to put this somewhere better than `get_context_data` for the ListView. That's not the right place at all. This probably needs to be triggered when the student submits their score for the current quiz.

Comment: It worked, thank you, change to student.total_score = total_score ['score__sum']

Answer (score 1):

On your `total_score = TakenQuiz.objects.aggregate(Sum('score'))` you are not picking any data. Use the get object first, then you update it.
Also, you are doing it in the ListView, not sure if that is the best recommended place to do it.